# How can I pass path to fs.createReadStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am fairly new to nodejs so please forgive me if I am asking for something very basic. I have built a script that writes data to a file which is then uploaded to slack.

This is what is written to file
// Write to File

```
let myFile = '/tmp/' + Date.now() + '.txt';
fs.writeFile(myFile, myReport, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
        console.log("The file was saved named: " + myFile);
 });
```

This is where I upload it to slack

```
const options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
    headers: slackHeaders,
    formData:
    {
        token: slackToken,
        channels: channelId,
        file: fs.createReadStream(path.join('/tmp/', Date.now() + '.txt')),
        filetype: 'text',
        title: 'Report',
    }
};
```

As the filename is changing, I tried using path.join('/tmp/', Date.now() + '.txt') but it gave me an error

> {"ok":false,"error":"upload_error"}

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), createReadStream can only accept " |  | ". If I pass in a manual path, it works fine but it doesn't work using path.join or myFile.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a difference in the filenames. Date.now() will be different each time it’s run as it’s creating time stamp for that exact millisecond. Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I even tried using myFile under fs.createReadStream but same results. Variable myFile has the current file name (including the date when it wrote the file)

Comment: Apologies I was going by the code you provided. Are you executing this sequentially? Nodejs is asynchronous and will execute the next command regardless of if the previous one has completed or not. To get around this you could use a callback function or promises.